# List comprehension missing some values versus writing loops

Tags: python

I have two data sets, `found` and `allowed`. I want to check if any of the observations in `found` do not appear in `allowed`, so that I can make sure to flag them as not being allowed.

```
found = [["A", "B", "C"], [10, 20, 30], ["X", "Y", "Z"]]
allowed = [["A", "B", "C", "D"], [20, 30, 40], ["W", "X", "Y"]]
```

If I run the following, I get the correct answer, which is `[(1, 10), (2, 'Z')]`

```
new_values = []
for x in range(0, len(allowed)):
    for val in found[x]:
        if val not in allowed[x]:
            new_values.append((x, val))
```

However, if I run the following, which requires fewer lines and I think is easier, it returns `new_values = [(2, 'Z')]`

```
for x in range(0, len(allowed)):
    new_values = [(x, val) for val in found[x] if val not in allowed[x]]
```

What happened to `(1, 10)`? If I run `10 in allowed[1]` I get `False`, which makes me think it should have appeared in `new_values`!

Comment: What data structure would you expect if there are multiple non-allowed in `found`?

Comment: As written above, the correct answer is `[(1, 10), (2, 'Z')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are re-assigning the `new_values` in the for loop:

```
for x in range(0, len(allowed)):
    new_values = [(x, val) for val in found[x] if val not in allowed[x]]
```

Try this:

```
new_values = []
for x in range(0, len(allowed)):
    new_values.extend([(x, val) for val in found[x] if val not in allowed[x]])
```

or, even shorter using list comprehensions:

```
new_values = [(x, val) for x in range(0, len(allowed)) for val in found[x] if val not in allowed[x]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new_values = [(x, val) for x, allowable in enumerate(allowed)
                        for val in found[x] if val not in allowable]
```

It is generally considered more Pythonic to use `enumerate` to iterate over a sequence if you also need the indices of the values.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting `enumerate` in the nested comprehension can shorten it up:

```
new_values = [(i, x) for i, f in enumerate(found) for x in f if x not in allowed[i]]
```